# What's the semantic difference between ERANGE and EOVERFLOW?

Tags: c, posix, semantics, errno

The `errno` value `ERANGE` is documented by POSIX as

> Result too large.

and `EOVERFLOW` is documented as

> Value too large to be stored in data type.

What's the semantic difference between these two? Especially considering that `ERANGE` is used by ISO 9899 (e.g. in `strtol`) with the semantic described for `EOVERFLOW`. Are these two `errno` values only distinct for historical reasons?

Please back up your arguments with appropriate sources if possible.

Comment: Suggest returning the favor of an appropriate source with "`EOVERFLOW` is documented as ..." since `ERANGE` in in the C11 spec and `EOVERFLOW` is not.

Comment: @chux That's why I say “documented by **POSIX** as.” The specific page is [errno.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html). ISO 9899 does not document the meaning of `ERANGE`.

Comment: I see - did not initial read "by POSIX " to apply to the 2nd line. - Certainly make s sense to read as you have posted/commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SingleUnix is quite verbose about `EOVERFLOW`:

> Value too large to be stored in data type The user ID or group ID of an IPC or file system object was too large to be stored into appropriate member of the caller-provided structure. This error will only occur on implementations that support a larger range of user ID or group ID values than the declared structure member can support. This usually occurs because the IPC or file system object resides on a remote machine with a larger value of the type uid_t, off_t or gid_t than the local system.

`EOVERFLOW` seems to be intended to signal a subsystem incompatibility, i.e. some system returned a larger value than another subsystem can handle.

`EOVERFLOW` is [explained in more detail](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_03) in the rationale:

> Most of the uses of this error code are related to large file support. Typically, these cases occur on systems which support multiple programming environments with different sizes for off_t, but they may also occur in connection with remote file systems.
>
> In addition, when different programming environments have different widths for types such as int and uid_t, several functions may encounter a condition where a value in a particular environment is too wide to be represented. In that case, this error should be raised. For example, suppose the currently running process has 64-bit int, and file descriptor 9223372036854775807 is open and does not have the close-on- exec flag set. If the process then uses execl() to exec a file compiled in a programming environment with 32-bit int, the call to execl() can fail with errno set to [EOVERFLOW]. A similar failure can occur with execl() if any of the user IDs or any of the group IDs to be assigned to the new process image are out of range for the executed file's programming environment.
>
> Note, however, that this condition cannot occur for functions that are explicitly described as always being successful, such as getpid().

Thanks to @rici for the pointer

`ERANGE` is more like *this won't ever fit*. `strtol()` is one example. Another, less clear one: Trying to increment a SYSV semaphore past its configured limit returns `ERANGE`.

With `EOVERFLOW` that data is there, it just does not fit into the local data structure(s).

For example, `lseek()` can return `EOVERFLOW`. This happens, e.g. when `off_t` is only 32bit but the file system can support larger files and you try to seek past the range the OS can handle. Why isn't this `ERANGE`? Because the system can handle the operation in principle, it just cannot return it to you in the data type available.

Trying to map more than 2G using `mmap()` on a 32bit system on Linux returns an `EOVERFLOW` (other systems return `EINVAL`).

Unfortunately, this is not totally consistent. For example, the bluetooth stack returns `EOVERFLOW` when it finds too many host controllers in the system.

Comment: There is even more explanation in the rationale (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_03), which also notes that the error `ERANGE` was added because it is used in the C standard. The example in the rationale of a 64-bit executable `execl` a 32-bit binary with an unclosed out-of-range fd is fascinating. I have no idea whether that happens.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the reference, I'll add the quote

Comment: @rici The example itself is a bit ridiculous but what can and does happen is people trying to exec a 32 bit program with an open file descriptor to a large file on systems where large files are only implemented for 64 bit programs.

Answer (score 4):

There is a semantic difference:

`EOVERFLOW` is used for the case where a buffer size os too small and the data transfer requested would overflow the destination buffer, or similar error conditions:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open_by_handle_at.2.html
>
> `EOVERFLOW`
>
> ```
>          The handle->handle_bytes value passed into the call was too
>           small.  When this error occurs, handle->handle_bytes is
>           updated to indicate the required size for the handle.
> ```
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html
>
> `EOVERFLOW`
>
> ```
>          pathname refers to a regular file that is too large to be
>           opened.  The usual scenario here is that an application
>           compiled on a 32-bit platform without -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
>           tried to open a file whose size exceeds (1<<31)-1 bytes; see
>           also O_LARGEFILE above.  This is the error specified by
>           POSIX.1; in kernels before 2.6.24, Linux gave the error EFBIG
>           for this case.
> ```

`ERANGE` is used for values that do not fit in the destination type (C99) and for arguments outside the defined range for specific commands (POSIX)

But it is also used in errors where `EOVERFLOW` would be more appropriate:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html
>
> ```
>   The pthread_setname_np() function can fail with the following error:
>
>  ERANGE The length of the string specified pointed to by name exceeds
>           the allowed limit.
>
>   The pthread_getname_np() function can fail with the following error:
>
>   ERANGE The buffer specified by name and len is too small to hold the
>           thread name.
> ```

I guess `EOVERFLOW` is used for system calls and `ERANGE` is used in C library functions, standard and not.